# Javascript - Prevent exponotial notation in style

Tags: javascript, styles, exponential

I have a script where I need to assign values for style.left but all borwsers convert integers into exponentials notation if superior to 1e+06 for webkit browser and superior to 1e+07 for others. Any exponential notation are not renderered in a style attribute (like for left, right, translate, etc...).

For example if I assign to a div this style manually:

```
div.style.left = 1000000+'px';
// or
div.style.left = '1000000px';
```

Both return in the browser (Google Chrome for example)

```
<div style="left: 1e+06px;"></div>
```

And this notation doesn't work to render a style property. It's quite strange that all browsers convert an integer superior to 1 000 000 (or 10 000 000) in exponential notation in a style attribute which doesn't support exponential notation... I tried to use .toPrecision() .toFixed(), etc... but all browsers treat css value after the value is assign.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you using such a large number? There are no displays with a million pixels.

Comment: On UHD screen and with a carousel, it 1000000px can be easily reached (100-200 slides). Or it the same with small numbers....

Answer (score 0):

Curious why you have to use such a huge numbers, but this works as intended

```
div.setAttribute('style', 'left: 1000000px')
```

Comment: This will remove any other styles that the element has.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It correctly format the style but it still break all browsers after a certain value. On UHD displays and with a carousel for example of 100-150 slides it can be reached easily. there are a lot of example where this kind of value can be reached (especially with small number also). So, it seems that all browser stop to render under and before a certain value... whatever the notation format...

Comment: In that case you should alter your layout. Position inner `div` relatively in a set of wide outer divs. Or a better solution could be to remove the element from DOM entirely after it reaches a certain distance and store it in memory. Hard to imagine how much memory would be consumed by keeping 100 fullscreen slides active on a page.